# Is there a pause function?

Tags: star-wars-rebellion

Going to the menu in SWR pauses the game, but is there a pause function in Star Wars Rebellion which allows you to pause the game while giving orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pause the game but won't be able to give any orders if you do.

However, it's possible to set the game to very slow speed by right clicking the speed bar and selecting the slow option, which should give you ample time to issue orders.